# Problema .toString() en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, vuejs

Estoy desarrollando una app en la que quiero usar MongoDB Atlas para bases de datos. Ya estoy registrado en su plataforma, tengo mi cluster y demás. En mi app uso Vue.js y este es el código de mi componente:

```js
import MongoClient from 'mongodb'

  export default {
    created: function() {

      const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@users-ugsck.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
      const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
      client.connect(err => {
        const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
        // perform actions on the collection object
        client.close();
      });

    }
  }
```

Obviamente los campos de  y  los reemplazo con los datos pero luego en consola me sale:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.eval (graceful-fs.js?0da7:63)
    at eval (graceful-fs.js:281)
    at Object../node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js (app.js:5192)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:767)
    at fn (app.js:130)
    at Object.eval (index.internals.js?898b:9)
    at eval (index.internals.js:124)
    at Object../node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/src/init/index.internals.js (app.js:5381)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:767)
    at fn (app.js:130)
```

EDIT: A veces el error varia, y en vez de ser el error de "toString", es un error con un módulo 'net'. Traté de instalarlo con npm pero el error no se resuelve.

Comment: Confirmo que la conexión a mongoDB está bien, pienso que el problema puede estar en como se esta tratando de usar "toString", ¿Podrías compartir más código? Por otro lado, hasta donde sé, la aplicación debe estar dentro del lexical scope del método "connect". Saludos

Comment: @g.4 El problema es que yo no estoy usando "toString" en mi código, por lo que yo deduzco que viene de uno de los paquetes o dependencias de mongodb